# Extra door seal mod

Tags: door, citroen, seal

I own a Citroen C1. It's a basic car, but one that is nice to modify and improve yourself.
My car doors only have a single door weatherstrip to stop water getting in, the passenger side has begun to fail and on both sides air gets into the car and at high speeds gets very noisy.

The gap between the edge of the door and the car is around an inch. What could I use to seal this gap effectively and could I use a seal like those shown here:
http://www.automobiletrim.com/door-seal-rubber.html

to put over the edge of the door to seal it, or will this just fall off?

or would I be better off using a product like this to seal it and deflect the water?

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/P-Type-Weatherbar-Draft-Draught-Excluding-Rubber-Seal-P-Shape-3-8M-Fit-All-Car-/121721580899?hash=item1c572bed63

Thank you.